# emulate human using open source browser

Tags: javascript, html, http, browser

I want to emulate some human(not for spam use) for some my daily works. I don't want to use some curl/wget solution because it will include some works to analyze the HTTP package sent by browser. So, basically:

1. I will use the browser(eg. chrome) to login the system, so I have login state in that browser.
2. I open the search page for the system, and by any way I start the script.
3. The script will input some string into the  input, and submit the form.
4. The browser redirects to the result page, and my script will analyze the result page and get the things I want.

Is there any existing solutions that I can use to write such script? The functionality should include:

1. fill in some  and submit the form
2. in the result page the script can analyze the webpage and get the desired data.

I was trying to do it in  but the domain for my program and the system that I want to run in is not in the same domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be interested in famous [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/):

> Selenium automates browsers. That's it. What you do with that power is
>   entirely up to you. Primarily it is for automating web applications
>   for testing purposes, but is certainly not limited to just that.
>   Boring web-based administration tasks can (and should!) also be
>   automated as well.

[See its DEMO here.](http://vimeo.com/4671653)

---

Or you may be interested in [iMacros addon of Firefox](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/firefox/) depending on your requirements.